# AngularJS Watch Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I need to code the following requirement. If it occurs that any form field changes, I need to hide a div with some content. My solution is using `$watch` with `objectEquality == true` for watching a complex object that bind to the form fields. But this complex object has around 100 fields to watch.

I think the solution described above addresses the requirement but I've read it could cause poor performance. So, is it the best solution? Do I have others alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

You may find that performance won't be an issue, 100 bindings isn't too bad. If you do need another solution though, you could put an ng-change listener on all the forms that want to watch, like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-change = "hideTheThing = true">
<div ng-hide = "hideTheThing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things that you think you need `$scope.$watch` for can and should probably be solved with an `ng-change`.

```
<input type="text" ng-change="formFieldChanged()">
```

Inside the function you can do whatver you like with other scope variables.